# Grouping and moving the remaining nodes of the matched row using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <case>
      <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
   </case>
   <results>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject1</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField1</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject2</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField2</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject3</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField3</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey4</IKEY>
         <OBJECTID>TestObject4</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField4</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
      </row>
   </results>
</response>
```

My requirement is to group all the matching `<IKEY>` rows & move them under one `<row>` and moving the `<OBJECTID>` & `<OBJECTPHYFILEID>` nodes that exists in the matched `<IKEY>` row(i.e in the same row) under that new node `<SourceInstance>`. Eventually my output xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <case>
      <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
   </case>
   <results>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey1</IKEY>
         <Sources>
            <SourceInstance>
               <OBJECTID>TestObject1</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField1</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
            </SourceInstance>
            <SourceInstance>
               <OBJECTID>TestObject2</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField2</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
            </SourceInstance>
            <SourceInstance>
               <OBJECTID>TestObject3</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField3</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
            </SourceInstance>
         </Sources>
      </row>
      <row>
         <IKEY>TestKey4</IKEY>
         <Sources>
            <SourceInstance>
               <OBJECTID>TestObject4</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField4</OBJECTPHYFILEID>
            </SourceInstance>
         </Sources>
      </row>
   </results>
</response>
```

I am trying with the following XSLT, but couldn't achieve the desired xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:key name="ikey" match="row" use="string(IKEY)" />
   <xsl:template match="results">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ikey', string(IKEY))[1])]" mode="ikey" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="row" mode="ikey">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="IKEY">
            <row>
               <IKEY>
                  <xsl:value-of select="//IKEY" />
               </IKEY>
               <Sources>
                  <xsl:for-each select="OBJECTID">
                     <SourceInstance>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//key('ikey', IKEY)/OBJECTID" />
                     </SourceInstance>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </Sources>
            </row>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sure that I am missing something here. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Where is the `<OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField3</OBJECTPHYFILEID>` data supposed to come from?

Comment: @Martin Honnen, I apologize for not adding the correct input xml to the question. I have added it now. You can see `<OBJECTPHYFILEID>ObjPhyField3</OBJECTPHYFILEID>` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `key()` function you can find all items in the current group and can then transform them as needed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="ikey" match="row" use="string(IKEY)" />

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ikey', string(IKEY))[1])]" mode="ikey" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="ikey">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="IKEY">
                <row>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="IKEY"/>
                    <Sources>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ikey', IKEY)"/>
                    </Sources>
                </row>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <SourceInstance>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::IKEY)]"/>
        </SourceInstance>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to take the data by specifying the nodes like `<OBJECTPHYFILEID>` `<OBJECTID>` etc.?. The reason for asking the question is that I have to take only few nodes .

Comment: I got it!! Something like below I should try:`<xsl:template match="row">
        <SourceInstance>
           <OBJECTID> <xsl:value-of select="OBJECTID"/></OBJECTID>
     <OBJECTPHYFILEID><xsl:value-of select="OBJECTPHYFILEID"/></OBJECTPHYFILEID>
        </SourceInstance>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Plus one for you.

Comment: Instead of using `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::IKEY)]"/>` which processes and copies all elements except `IEKY` you can of course also specify the elements you want with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="OBJECTID | OBJECTPHYFILEID"/>`